# Continuous time markov chain backward/forward equations

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

[image]

Using Kolmogorov's forward and backward equations, show that $p_{11}(t) + p_{21}(t) + p_{31}(t) = 1$ and $p_{21}(t) = p_{31}(t)$ where $p_{ij}(t) = P(X(t) = j | X(0) = i)$.

**My attempt:**

I can show the first part but not the second, that is, for all $t \ge 0$, the forward equations for $p_{11}$, $p_{21}$, and $p_{31}$ are as follows:
\begin{gather}
 p_{11}'(t) = \lambda p_{12}(t) + \lambda p_{13}(t) - 2\lambda p_{11}(t)  \cdots (1)\\
 p_{21}'(t) = \lambda p_{22}(t) + \lambda p_{23}(t) - 2\lambda p_{21}(t) \\
 p_{31}'(t) = \lambda p_{32}(t) + \lambda p_{33}(t) - 2\lambda p_{31}(t) 
\end{gather}

The backward equations for $p_{11}$, $p_{21}$, and $p_{31}$ are as follows:
\begin{gather}
p_{11}'(t) = \lambda p_{21}(t) + \lambda p_{31}(t) - 2\lambda p_{11}(t) \cdots (2) \\
p_{21}'(t) = \lambda p_{11}(t) + \lambda p_{31}(t) - 2\lambda p_{21}(t) \\
p_{31}'(t) = \lambda p_{11}(t) + \lambda p_{21}(t) - 2\lambda p_{31}(t)
\end{gather}

Subtracting $(1)$ from $(2)$ yields,
\begin{gather}
0 = p_{21}(t) - p_{12}(t) + p_{31}(t) - p_{13}(t) 
\end{gather}

Noting that $1-p_{11}(t) = p_{12}(t) + p_{13}(t)$, we have:
\begin{gather*}
0 = p_{21}(t) + p_{31}(t) - (1-p_{11}(t)) \\
\implies p_{11}(t) + p_{21}(t) + p_{31}(t) = 1
\end{gather*}

However, I'm not exactly sure how to show $p_{21}(t) = p_{31}(t)$ from algebraic manipulations... (I can show it by actually solving the differential equation but the question wants me to show it through manipulation)

Comment: One way is to note that $Q$ does not change when rows $2$ and $3$ and columns $2$ and $3$ are simultaneously permuted.  However, that permutation interchanges $p_{21}(t)$ and $p_{31}(t).$

Comment: Thanks. Is there an algebraic way?

Comment: That *is* algebraic.  What do *you* mean by "algebraic," then?

Comment: What happens with this question? Is it left in disarray, just to clutter the site?